# Webscrape app not finding correct HTML container

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my first webscraping application type.

Here's my code:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url= 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card'

#opening up connection, grabbing page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#makes it a variablepage_html = uClient.read()

page_html = uClient.read()
#will close it
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each container in HTML
containers = page_soup.find("div",{"class":"item-container"})

filename = "Products.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, product_name, shipping\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    brand = containers.div.div.a["title"]

    title_container = containers.find("a", {"class": "item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].txt

    shipping_container = container.find("li", {"class": "price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].txt.strip()

    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
    print("shipping: " + shipping)

    f.write(brand + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + shipping + "\n")
f.close()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-b9aa37e3923c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/Mohit/Documents/Python/webscrape.py', wdir='/Users/Mohit/Documents/Python')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/Mohit/Documents/Python/webscrape.py", line 38, in <module>
    brand = containers.div.div.a["title"]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Basically, what I want it to do is grab the brand, product name, and shipping price of all the graphics cards on the page and format them into a CSV.

I think the program can't locate the image or where the data should be imported from. This is my first webscraping project and I was using `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI&t=800s` as a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're accessing properties of some variables without checking whether they exist or not. For example in this line: (that gave the Exception you're experiencing; but also in other lines in your code...)

```python
brand = containers.div.div.a["title"]
```

I suggest a much more careful approach. For example, this naive code:

```
if (containers is not None) and (containers.div is not None) and (containers.div.div is not None) and (containers.div.div.a is not None):
  brand = containers.div.div.a["title"]
else:
  brand = ""
```

If you'd like to further debug the problem in the specific HTML you got, try nested conditions:

```
if containers is not None:
  if containers.div is not None:
    # ... more conditions here ...
  else:
    print "ERROR 2: containers.div was None! :("
else:
  print "ERROR 1: containers was None! :("
```

Comment: Or, you could simply use `try-except`.

Comment: Suppose someone wants to *debug* the actual code or the specific HTML returned (a common practice when writing a crawler/scraper, as well as when monitoring a crawler over time), e.g. determine where exactly a `NoneType` object was encountered in expressions like `container.div.div.a["title"]`. How can we do that without multiple conditionals (or multiple `try-except` statements, for that matter)?